# How to match two different length and different column text file with header using join command in linux

Tags: linux, shell, join

I have two different length text files A.txt and B.txt

A.txt looks like :

```
ID  pos  val1  val2  val3
1   2    0.8     0.5   0.6
2   4    0.9     0.6   0.8
3   6    1.0     1.2   1.3
4   8    2.5     2.2   3.4
5   10   3.2     3.4   3.8
```

B.txt looks like :

```
pos category
2    A
4    B
6    A
8    C
10   B
```

I want to match pos column and in both files and want the output like this

```
ID  catgeory  pos  val1  val2  val3
1      A       2    0.8     0.5   0.6
2      B       4    0.9     0.6   0.8
3      A       6    1.0     1.2   1.3
4      C       8    2.5     2.2   3.4
5      B       10   3.2     3.4   3.8
```

I used the join function `join -1 2 -2 1 <(sort -k2 A.txt)  <(sort -k1 B.txt) > C.txt`

The C.txt comes without a header

```
    1      A       2    0.8     0.5   0.6
    2      B       4    0.9     0.6   0.8
    3      A       6    1.0     1.2   1.3
    4      C       8    2.5     2.2   3.4
    5      B       10   3.2     3.4   3.8
```

I want to get output with a header from the join function. kindly help me out

Thanks in advance

Comment: When I run your `join` command, I get totally different column orders and a header on the last line in C.txt.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are ok with `awk`, could you please try following. Written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} ($2 in a){$2=a[$2] OFS $2} 1' B.txt A.txt | column -t
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                       ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                    ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when B.txt is being read.
  a[$1]=$2                  ##Creating array a with index of 1st field and value is 2nd field of current line.
  next                      ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
($2 in a){                  ##Checking condition if 2nd field is present in array a then do following.
  $2=a[$2] OFS $2           ##Adding array a value along with 2nd field in 2nd field as per output.
}
1                           ##1 will print current line.
' B.txt A.txt | column -t   ##Mentioning Input_file names and passing awk program output to column to make it look better.
```

Comment: thanks, @ravinderSingh13 but am looking same in the join function

Comment: @Jammy, When I run command `join -1 2 -2 1 <(sort -k2 A.txt)  <(sort -k1 B.txt)` I could see header is coming but at very last line, but you mentioned you are not getting header at all in your question, could you please clarify this once?

Answer (score 1):

As you requested... It is perfectly possible to get the desired output using just GNU `join`:

```
$ join -1 2 -2 1 <(sort -k2 -g A.txt)  <(sort -k1 -g B.txt) -o 1.1,2.2,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5
ID category pos val1 val2 val3
1 A 2 0.8 0.5 0.6
2 B 4 0.9 0.6 0.8
3 A 6 1.0 1.2 1.3
4 C 8 2.5 2.2 3.4
5 B 10 3.2 3.4 3.8
$
```

The key to getting the correct output is using the `sort -g` option, and specifying the `join` output column order using the `-o` option.

To "pretty print" the output, pipe to `column -t`

```
$ join -1 2 -2 1 <(sort -k2 -g A.txt)  <(sort -k1 -g B.txt) -o 1.1,2.2,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5 | column -t
ID  category  pos  val1  val2  val3
1   A         2    0.8   0.5   0.6
2   B         4    0.9   0.6   0.8
3   A         6    1.0   1.2   1.3
4   C         8    2.5   2.2   3.4
5   B         10   3.2   3.4   3.8
$
```